# around: adverb or preposition

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> He couldn't even enjoy the school holidays and spent his time moping **around** the house.

Is the word "around" in the above sentence used as a preposition or as an adverb?

I think it is used as a preposition. However, others disagree.

Comment: ***to mope around*** is pretty much a "phrasal verb" (cf ***to loaf about, to kick back, to lounge around***). The second element would normally be called a preposition in such constructions. But honestly, what difference does it make which particular round [pigeon]hole you shove this particular square peg into?

Comment: It's a preposition functioning as head of the preposition phrase "around the house", which has the noun phrase "the house" as its complement. Note that the verb is just "moped", not "moped around".

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to classify.  My guess is that "around" is part of the verb "mope around".  If it were a preposition, it ought to be okay to say *"Around what did he mope?" or *"the house around which he moped".  If it were an adverb, it ought to be possible to shift it to a different position: *"He moped the house around."

Comment: More to the point, we could just say ***he moped around***. There's no particular reason to mention ***where*** he moped at all, let alone try to convey the exact nature of his [potentially, dynamically changing] spatial relationship to the environment within which he moped.

Answer (score 1):

> *He couldn't even enjoy the school holidays and spent his time moping*
>   *around the house*.

I'd say that "around" is a preposition functioning as head of the preposition phrase "around the house", with the noun phrase "the house" as its complement.

The PP "around the house" is a complement licensed by "moping", and hence "moping around the house" is a syntactic constituent with "moping" as head and the PP "around the house" as its complement.

But "moping around" is not a constituent at word level: it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s “moping” that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have [1] not [2]:

[1] They were moping around the house.

[2] *They were mope arounding the house.

Comment: +1 If we're going to use *moped* as a verb, shouldn't it be *mopeded* around? (And isn't it dangerous to use your moped in a house?)

Comment: @Araucaria LOL! I did it that way in [2]to show that the inflection is not on "around", but on "moping", thus "mope around" cannot possibly be a constituent at word level, i.e. a compound verb. I used "moping" because that was the form used in the OP's example. If it had been "They moped around the house", I would have  used the _ed_ form in [2]  *"They mope arounded".

Comment: Yes, I noted that. Just needed to get the vespa joke in there somehow!